# How do I clear a page in html using javascript? Like clear everything

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with a story line. Half way in the story the "narrator" says he will take away everything on the page. How do I do that? In command form obviously. And I want it to be just temporary, reload the page and it will be fine.
And in javascript
thanks

Comment: Have you tried to simply hide the body ?

Answer (score 2):

One way for clearing your page is this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.innerHTML = '';
        </script>
```

Just make sure the above code to insert it just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Right right, thank you. My brain is just not functioning today, last resort was good ol stack overflow